# Use -i option of ssh for rsync

Tags: ssh, rsync

Normally I login with ssh -i

like

```
ssh -i ./ssh/MyAws.pms ec2-user@sadafasada.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

However now I want to use rsync with ssh.

```
rsync -av ./ ec2-user@sadafasada.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user/coding/
```

where can I set -i option or is it impossible???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to place the options (including `-i`) in your ssh configuration file, `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host sadafasada
    HostName sadafasada.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
    User ec2-user
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/MyAws.pms
```

Then connect using

```
ssh sadafasada
```

or

```
rsync -av ./ sadafasada:coding/
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the rsync `-e` option:

`-e 'ssh -i'`

*This option allows you to choose an alternative remote shell program (...) Command-line arguments are permitted in COMMAND  provided  that  COMMAND  is presented  to  rsync as a single argument.*

Comment: this also could be a solution. let me try. thanks very much